# ROS2 ROS_ERROR_STREAM equivalent

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an equivalent to the stream log functions in ROS1?

I only found the RCLCPP_ERROR which is an equivalent for the ROS_ERROR.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310842/ros2-ros_error_stream-equivalent/) by [Flautz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33500/flautz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-12-17**:
Unless something has changed since I last looked at the macros, there's no equivalent for this in ROS 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Available in ROS2 as of Eloquent. https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/926

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2020-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The stream operators have not been implemented in rclcpp yet.

You can get an overview of the logging API here: http://docs.ros2.org/crystal/api/rclcpp/logging_8hpp.html

If that's something that you'd like to see we'd be happy to have a contribution to add support for stream style macros. Before you implement too much I suggest opening a ticket to discuss the best approach here: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2